# Disable stemming in search

Tags: support, search

Is there a syntax to explicitly disable word stemming in the search Q&A?

For example, I want to search for usages of [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), a built-in python function, and I want to disable stemming of that word otherwise there are many irrelevant results that use terms such as "local variable".

*Edit:  The answer below does not work, nor any of the suggestions in the comments below it, and I am still searching for an acceptable answer to this question.  There does not seem to be a way to add bounties on meta questions, otherwise I would have added one here..*

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the word(s) you want to search for into double quotes. In this case, you have to search for the following:

```
"locals"
```

(probably combined with `[python]` considering you're looking for posts about a Python function)

Comment: Hmmm, nope, no good.  It removes uses I *do* want, which look like `locals()`.

Comment: `[python] code:"locals"`

Comment: @TinyGiant  still not working ... searching `user:me code:"locals"` finds zero results, but it should find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13117020/674039) result, amongst others ...

Comment: [`user:674039 code:"locals()"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A674039+code%3A%22locals%28%29%22)

Comment: @TinyGiant Yeah, but that kinda misses the point, doesn't it? If you know exactly what the code snippet looks like, there's no need to search. What about a method with parameters?

Comment: Indeed, it misses the point.  It still does not find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13117020/674039) result, as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Basic You're providing conflicting requirements.  You want the search to sometimes* look for instances where the entire token matches that text, and you want it to sometimes not look for just that token, and instead look for instances where it's just a part of a token.  You can do one or the other, but you can't *sometimes* let it be a part of the token and sometimes not, based on whether or not it's a token you want to match.

Comment: Isn't the point that if you search for `locals()` and get results, that searching for `locals` should give those same results plus possibly any more that match? This is not happening.

Comment: @Servy Actually, I think what we're looking for here is a tokeniser that understands code better, but until then, the ability to do an exact string match that doesn't neccesarly match token boundaries would do nicely.

Comment: @Basic All you need to do for that is to remove the quotes.  The problem is that when he looks for matches that aren't a complete token he gets lots of false positives.

Comment: @DavidG That's because you're going out of your way to use an exact match.  If you don't want an exact match, then don't tell it to search for an exact match.  You can do one or the other, but you can't say, "search for the specific inexact matches that I personally care about, while not ever searching for the inexact matches that I'm not interested in" because the computer can't read your mind.

Comment: @Basic Indeed.  When you turn off exact matching, you get results that aren't an exact match.

Comment: Just saw your edit.... What is imprecise about "give me every document that contains the string `locals`"? I'll stop now to avoid pointless clutter...

Comment: @Servy The problem is the tokenizer finds `local`, which he does _not_ want.  Requirement is "find every string that begins with `locals`".  More advanced search options (for example, SQL LIKE syntax even) would help that.

Comment: Wait... you mean the search function is less than perfect, leaves something to be desired, and has a few quirks? Say it ain't so.

Comment: As I understand it, the desired requirement is to search for the exact **word** `locals`. The string `locals()` is not a word, it's a word followed by  `()`.

Comment: Can SQL "like" search for whole words only? How?

Comment: I remember a time when regular expressions were the key piece of any respectable search function. Then the web came. Now you grunt at the machine, it guesses what you meant, and you can only get what you want if you guess what it's going to guess. Progress.

Comment: @artem That doesn't make sense. You're implying that in this sentence, the word "sentence" is not a word, because it is followed by a comma?

Comment: @MrLister No that's not what I was trying to say. I'll try one more time. "Stemming" implies word search, so if I give it a word "locals" in quotes, indicating that I want that exact word form, it does not make sense that "locals()" is not shown in the result.